# hasClass() starts with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible and how do I use `hasClass()` so that I can search for classes that start with some specified string?
I want to look at multiple classes to see if there exists at least one class that starts with a string.

```
string: "old"
```

Is this possible and are you also able to do contains or wildcard searching?

Comment: Provide what you have done...

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("old"); ...

Comment: sounds like a better solution is to use multiple classes so you do not have to look at partials. but you can use an attribute selector, but there is no looking for each individual class name and see what it starts.

Comment: like `$("*[class*='mystring']")`

Comment: @epascarello i need to look at partials because i am using multiple classes with prefixes

Comment: My suggestion is to add another class so you do not need to look for partials.

Comment: @Jonasw how does that get elements with classes that start with old?

Comment: @epascarello there are many classes with prefixes. adding more classes doesnt alleviate the fact that i need to look for a category of classes, whose category is determined by the prefixes. unless u can propose something that works

Comment: Well you are going to have false positives so you will need to filter out those since there is no way to match of partial classes. You can look to see if a string is in the classlist.

Comment: @epascarello yeah its looking that way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

selector will be : `[class^=old]`

Thus :

```
$('[class^=old]')
```

## Syntax :

- `[attr^=vvv]` => Select all elements have attribute `attr` ,its value starts with `vvv`.
- `[attr$=vvv]` => Select all elements have attribute `attr` ,its value ends with `vvv`.
- `[attr*=vvv]` => Select all elements have attribute `attr` ,its value contains  `vvv`.

## `Is` not `hasClass` :

In your case , `is` method is suitable more than `hasClass` :

```
 if (element.is('[class^=old]')){


  }
```

And not

```
 if (element.hasClass('[class^=old]')){


  }
```

## JQuery Plugin :

```
$.fn.hasClassStartsWith=function(prefix){
    return $(this).is(`[class^=${prefix}]`);
};
```

Then :

```
if (element.hasClassStartsWith('old')){
     // do your staff
}
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/t2kz2ov7/)

Comment: Is it helpful ? @agent

Comment: its very helpful, but when i use is("[class^=old]") i get false...
is("[class*=old]") is coming up true, as expected.
maybe is([class=]) doesnt look at each class individually but all classes together as one string? whereas hasClass(selector) looks at each class to see if one of the classes is the selector?

Comment: i have multiple classes on that object and several possible classes can have that string prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it would need to be a two part check. You can run a selector to find any class that contains the word.

now that is going to find "old", "cold", "bold". The reason you can not use starts with, because a class can be "foo old" and that does not start with old.

So what can you do, well you can use contains, than you can loop through and match with a regular expression to see if the classlist has a word that starts with it.

```js
var elems = $('[class*="old"]').filter( function () {
    return $(this).attr("class").match(/(^|\s)old/);
} ).addClass("picked");
```

```css
.picked { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="old">old</div>
<div class="old-asdf">old-asdf</div>
<div class="foo-old-asdf">foo-old-asdf</div>
<div class="cold">cold</div>
<div class="old foo">old foo</div>
<div class="foo old">foo old</div>
<div class="foo olddoo">foo olddoo</div>
<div class="foo ald">foo ald</div>
```